# How do I set selected item in a combobox class?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have populated a combobox with list class.

```
cboParentMenu.DataSource = listMenu;
cboParentMenu.DisplayMember = "caption";
```

This is the class variables.

```
public string caption { get; set; }
public string caption_style { get; set; }
public string cat_id { get; set; }
public int id_menu { get; set; }
```

Now, how do I set the selected item using the field id_menu? I'm thinking something like this one.

```
cboParentMenu.SelectedItem.id_menu = 123;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
cboParentMenu.SelectedItem = listMenu.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id_menu == 123);
```

Make sure you import `System.Linq`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cboParentMenu.SelectedValue = listMenu.Find(i => i.id_menu == 123);
```

Comment: If nothing is found, an exception will be thrown. So you better use FirstOrDefault instead of Find. In that case, the result will be null then nothing is selected.